# Problem of executing asynchronous functions without updating in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, rest, swiftui

When I add a product to the cart, it calculates the total price without changing the amount of the product in the cart.

This is how I add products to the cart:

```
@Published var cartProducts = [CartProduct]()
private let httpDownloader = HttpDownloader()
@Published var cartItemCount = 0
@Published var totalAmount: Double = 0

func getUserProducts() {
    httpDownloader.fetchUserProducts() { (result) in
        switch result {

        case .success(let cartProducts):
            if let cartProducts = cartProducts {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.cartProducts = cartProducts
                }
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error fetching products: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

func addProductToCart(id: Int, quantity: Int) {
    httpDownloader.addProductToCart(productId: id, quantity: quantity) { result in
        switch result {

        case .success:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.getUserProducts()

                print(self.cartProducts.first?.quantity ?? 0)

                self.calculateTotalPrice(products: self.cartProducts)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error fetching products: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

For example, the amount of product in the cart is currently 4. When I add an item to the cart, 4 is printed on the screen and the price is calculated accordingly. Then, when I send a request to Postman, I see that the amount of products in the cart has increased to 5.
I think the problem occurs because the amount of items in the cart is updated exactly and the app calculates the total price before it is captured.

Github repository address of the project: https://github.com/mehmetozkn/swiftui-computer-store-app

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct, the `calculateTotalPrice(products: cartProducts)` gets done before `getProduts()` is finished, giving you the wrong results because in getProduts() `httpDownloader.fetchProducts()` is asynchronous.
So you could try using a `completion handler` for `getProduts(completion: @escaping ....)`, or the `async/await` concurrency to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by calling the calculateTotal function here

```
func getUserProducts() {
        homeService.fetchUserProducts(path: .getProductByUserId) { (result) in
            switch result {

            case .success(let cartProducts):
                if let cartProducts = cartProducts {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.cartProducts = cartProducts
                        self.calculateTotalPrice()
                    }
                   
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching user products: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an async issue, not a SwiftUI issue.

Your `getUserProducts()` function starts a network request, and then returns immediately before it completes. Your `addProductToCart()` function calls `getUserProducts()`, and expects the results to be available as soon as `getUserProducts()` returns. Async code doesn't work that way.

I suggest reading up on async await and rewriting your function using async.

Alternatively you could rewrite your `getUserProducts()` to take a completion handler.

Fixing your whole app is more than I'm ready to take on, but here are some steps towards using async:

Rewrite your getUserProducts function to be async:

```
    func getProduts() {
        httpDownloader.fetchProducts() { (result) in
            switch result {

            case .success(let products):
                if let products = products {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.products = products
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching products: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

For that to work you'll also need to rewrite your fetchUserProducts() function to also be async:

```
    func fetchUserProductsAsync() async throws -> [CartProduct]? {
        guard let url = URL(string: userProductsURL) else {
            throw(NetworkException.notFound)
        }
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([CartProduct].self, from: data)
        return result
    }
```

And then in your `addProductToCart` function, you could wrap your call to `getUserProducts` in a `Task`:

```
    func addProductToCart(id: Int, quantity: Int) {
        httpDownloader.addProductToCart(productId: id, quantity: quantity) { result in
            switch result {

            case .success:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    Task {
                        await self.getUserProducts()
                        self.calculateTotalPrice(products: self.cartProducts)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching products: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

### Edit:

If instead you want to use completion handlers, a naive rewrite of your `getUserProducts()` function might look like this:

```
    func getUserProducts(completion: () -> Void) {
        httpDownloader.fetchUserProducts() { (result) in
            switch result {

            case .success(let cartProducts):
                if let cartProducts = cartProducts {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.cartProducts = cartProducts

                    }
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching products: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

And then call it like this:

```
    func addProductToCart(id: Int, quantity: Int) {
        httpDownloader.addProductToCart(productId: id, quantity: quantity) { result in
            switch result {

            case .success:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.getUserProducts() {
                        self.calculateTotalPrice(products: self.cartProducts)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching products: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I say that's a a naive rewrite because your code puts the results of the network calls into global variables, which is not great practice. It should really be rewritten to pass the resulting array (or an error) to the completion handler, and let the completion handler save the results as needed.)

Comment: I tried to solve the problem with the async/await method, but then I realized that the current Swiftui version does not support it in some places.
Then I started trying the other way ->
I updated my code using completion handlers as you showed, but I noticed that the 'calculateTotalPrice' method in the .'getUserProducts()' function was not working, so this method did not work.